# How to increase the drag and drop area in dropzone.js?

Tags: dropzone.js

I am using dropzoneJs to upload video in my project. But it has taking only from some area. Below image shows that area.

[image: dropzone area1]

I want to increase the area of upload like below image shows,

[image]

How to do this please help me.

### Code

```
 <tr class="tb-upload-content">
    <td class="label-info">
       <label for="">Content</label>
    </td>
    <td class="td-form-item">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="upload-drag">
             <div id="dropzone_<?php echo $unique_id;?>" class="dropzone">
                <h5 class="sm black">Upload file Here</h5>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: What is your code structure ?

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see without you providing your HTML code you can do something like this in your CSS:

```
.dz-default {
 width: 594px;
 height: 115px;
}
```

You might need to add some negative margin to the class as well as I presume the box will go 115px down from where it is positioned now. So figure out how much space there is from the top until the start of the div and then add that as -margin-top. Same for margin-left. As the .dz-default class obviously has some padding or margin left already.